# How could I have my Windows form stick to the corner of a window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to have my form to stick to the lower-left corner of the currently active window.

I can work out how to optimally update the position myself, but I'm not sure how I could reposition the form relative to the coordinates/size of a window, or even get that kind of information. Is there a decent way of doing this?

Comment: Web forms?  Win Forms?  WPF?  MVC?

Comment: You want to infect other programs with your ride-along program?  I think you'll need:  GetForegroundWindow().   And you'll have to poll to watch for position/focus changes.

Comment: Do you know that you can open the form in question within your main  window? It will be movable and you can set coordinates so it will stick to whatever place you want. This is because form is derived from control. Get the idea?

Comment: @T.S.  He will need to make sure that the [`TopLevel Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel(v=vs.110).aspx) is false also

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to do, Steve. I've found that GetWindowRect is likely what I'll need for the repositioning, unless I'm not understanding what T.S. mentioned.